# File input JS onchange, onclick not firing

Tags: javascript, file-io, asp-classic, onclick, onchange

I am trying to populate an input, of type text, with the the file name that has been selected. From what I have read sometimes you have to set the value to "" or null **onClick** then **onchange** set the place holder.

I have tried many different variations, but it just doesn't seem to fire. What am I overlooking?

My very basic example....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    getElementById("upFile").onClick = function(){
        this.value = "";
    }

    getElementById("upFile").onchange = function(){
        getElementById("uploadName").value = this.value;
    }
</script>


    <input type="text" name="uploadName" id="uploadName" placeholder="Attachment Title">
    <input type="file" id="upFile" name="upFile" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
```

What I have read

[Changing the placeholder text based on the users choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18194763/changing-the-placeholder-text-based-on-the-users-choice)

[Change placeholder text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506481/change-placeholder-text)

[Upload files using input type="file" field with .change() event not always firing in IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10214947/upload-files-using-input-type-file-field-with-change-event-not-always-firin)

[HTML input file selection event not firing upon selecting the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030686/html-input-file-selection-event-not-firing-upon-selecting-the-same-file)

None of which seem to be my issue...

Comment: try moving the script tag after the html

Comment: Check your browser console for errors. Unless you've arranged otherwise, it's `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @Brian I just tried, no luck.

Comment: @Brian However I do not think that is the issue being I have a working script above the html doing something different

Comment: @Pointy Sorry that is a typo I do have `document.getElementById()`. I've gotten crap for editing my Q's before. it would be appropriate to edit my Q now, no?

Comment: Have you looked in your browser's inspector to see what errors are showing up?

Comment: Had to make sure, it's always a good idea to add scripts after elements anyway. I'm browsing through my projects for image uploads, fairly certain I've done something similar before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. You can get rid of the onclick event listener, and watch for changes instead. The file upload element creates an array of files and you can access it like so:

```
<input type="text" name="uploadName" id="uploadName" placeholder="Attachment Title">
<input type="file" id="upFile" name="upFile" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<script>
    document.getElementById("upFile").onchange = function(){
        // single file selection, get the first file in the array
        document.getElementById("uploadName").value = this.files[0].name; 
    }
</script>
```

FYI:
This is what happens if the script tag is before the element. It runs the script once read and says it can't find the element referenced with `document.getElementById("upFile")`

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onchange' of null
>       at :2:48

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize it stored the values in an array. Thank you.

Comment: @gflynn94 No problemo

Answer (score 1):

You are missing document.getElementById and onClick should be onclick